# sql table join get rows form one table only

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following A,B with columns c1,c2

```
A
--
aId

B
--
bId, aId
```

Lets say A has the folowing rows

```
aid
1
3
4
```

and B has the following rows

```
bId, aId
6, 1
5, 4
10, 1
```

I need an output of the following

```
id
1
4
```

**Issue** That is, I am trying to get all rows in table A such that A.aId exists for some row in table B for column aId. I have tried using inner join but it gives me to many rows (in the above example it would give me row `1` twice).

Comment: have you tried LEFT JOIN with DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Comment: Suppose `A.aid` column have one another row with value `4`. then what is expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query seems to get your desired results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.aid) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.aid = b.aid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `A` on a subquery on `B` :

```
select * from A where aId in (select aId from B)
```

If the only column you want from `A` is `aID`, you already have it in `B` :

```
select distinct aId from B
```